# Constant 3d manipulators size

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Im trying to add 3d manipulators to a small 3d editor mine. I manage to draw them in ortho or perspective projection and use the camera location and the selected object distance to insure that the size is constant. However that does not work well... (ie if the fov of the camera in the perspective projection is changing the size of the manipulators are not constant anymore).

What I would like to achieve is like in Blender, the 3d manipulators always have a constant size regardless of the projection the 3d view/quad view is projecting.

I already try to draw the manipulators using an ortho projection, which insure that the size of the manipulators are constant in pixels, however when draw on top of a perspective view the manipulators look distorted and not "aligned" with the perspective view 3d drawing.

How can I achieve a constant manipulator size always "aligned" regardless of the projection type the 3d view is drawing?

Comment: If you draw the manipulators orthographically you are using another transform than the rest of your scene (which you draw with a normal perspective transform.) That's what gives you the distorted look.

Comment: True, what Im interested to know is how Blender do it, their manipulators always look good and "constant" regardless of the underlying view. I check the source code but cannot make any sense out of it...

Comment: Same with Maya and Houdini, don't you think they just draw them in clip space or something?

Comment: What do you mean clip space? You mean gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;

Comment: The space of the "viewport", so to speak. http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/10/05/clip-space/

Comment: I think that Blender generates the manipulator geometry parametrically (thereby always having correct proportions/scaling, depending on what it's being applied to). Also, you will notice that the 3d geometry of the object occludes the geometry for the manipulator, therefore it is _not_ being drawn in a separate (post-geometry) pass.

Comment: The manipulators in Blender are always draw on top of the geometry... and are not occluded...